# git cherry shows a new commit as cherry-picked when an identical commit was cherry-picked in the past

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry

Assume that there are two branches branch1 and branch2 and there is a test.txt on both the branches with the following line "opt:true".

Change the value from "true" to "false" on both the branches.

On branch1, change the value from "false" to "true" and commit it.

```
"git cherry branch2 branch1"
```

shows that the latest commit is not cherry-picked to branch2.

> + dc703edb4cf0f90fa1b5294cc5bea5c63c849229

On branch1, change the value from "true" to "false" and commit it.

```
"git cherry branch2 branch1"
```

shows that the latest commit is cherry-picked (though it is not cherry-picked) as there is an identical commit already on branch2.

> /+ dc703edb4cf0f90fa1b5294cc5bea5c63c849229
>   /- 9d767893962c0dd0d957e2c038bb2ef06df2fee3

Is there a way to git the true list of commits on branch1 that are not cherry-picked to branch2?

Comment: Why do you want to know specifically what's been cherry-picked? Why isn't that they're equivalent enough?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to git the true list of commits on branch1 that are not cherry-picked to branch2?

`git cherry` doesn't show you what has been cherry-picked, git doesn't record that information. It shows you *which commits are equivalent* and which are not. It's basically a commit-by-commit diff.

The purpose of `git cherry` is to let you know what commits have been applied or will yet be applied if you were to rebase. In that sense, the output of `git cherry` is correct.